# Is a boundary of a closure of set equal to boundary of that set?

Tags: general-topology

I can find a counter example by considering the set of all rational numbers in (a,b). Am I correct?

Comment: I am not sure about the example

Comment: Yes, provided that $a<b$. If $a<b$ then $\partial (\Bbb Q\cap (a,b)\;)=$ $[a,b]\ne \{a,b\} =$ $\partial ([a,b])=$ $\partial (\;\overline {\Bbb Q \cap (a,b)}\;).$... because  both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space.

If $M\subset X$, then $\partial M=\overline M\cap\overline{X\setminus M}$.

Then, $\partial \overline M=\overline M\cap\overline{X\setminus\overline M}$.

To find a counterexample, you need a set $M$ such that $\overline{X\setminus \overline M}\neq\overline{X\setminus M}$. Since $M\subset \overline M$, we have that $\overline{X\setminus\overline M}\subset\overline{X\setminus M}$. Then, there must exits some $x\in\overline {X\setminus M}$ that is not in $\overline{X\setminus\overline M}$.

This implies that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\subset\overline M$, although no such neighbourhood should be contained in $M$. That is, $\overline M$ must have interior points that are not interior points of $M$.

Then, a good example should be a set with no interior points that is dense in a closed ball of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: suggestion: you can use `\mathring M` notation for the interior.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that counterexample works: the boundary is $[a, b]$, but the closure of the set is $[a, b]$ which has boundary $\{a, b\}$.

Note that technically you need to require $a<b$.

(Another counterexample, in the same spirit, would be $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.)